# my php code is in my form i dont know how to fix this

Tags: php, html

Hi i am currently coding for a school project i am not a master in coding.
I am making a form using php and html with wampserver.
Some of my php code stays in the boxes wich u have to put your name in etc.
Can you please help me. Below is my php code and html. i tried everything w3schools and other stuff but still cant fix it please help me

i tried to begin over and now if i click the send button i get an error.

error code:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in C:\wamp64\www\web\formprocessor.php on line 4. i did tried to delete some & but still didnt work.

this is my code

```
&Naam=&_POST["&fNaam"]
&Email=&_POST["&fEmail"]


echo("Hallo &myNaam <br />");
echo("&myEmail isje mail.<br />");
```

Comment: Add your code in your question not as an image

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] (pictures do not count as code)

Comment: i tried and it didnt let me so thats why i did it this way

Answer (score 0):

1. change your contact.html to another file name with .php extension
2. replace contact.php in form action

Comment: i did this and now my code is showing on the page nothing else

Comment: paste your coding, instead of upload as an image